# How to find the data between month in entityframework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I had requirement to display the data of this month (between month starting to ending data )
I know how to do in MySQL  below query

```
enter code here select  @MonthAmount := IFNULL(sum(AmountReceived), 0.0) as TotoalAmountperMonth  
    from collection 
    where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') 
        and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month ) and AgentID=v_agent) as monthamount
```

but how to do using entity (lambda expression) I am new to entity when I google I got to get the data of today but in month?

below query got the result of today data

```
enter code here  var newAuctionsResults = repo.FindAllAuctions()
                    .Where(a => a.IsActive == true 
                                || (a.StartTime.Value.Year == todayYear
                                    && a.StartTime.Value.Month == todayMonth
                                    && a.StartTime.Value.Day == todayDay))
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
var newAuctionsResults = repo.FindAllAuctions()
  .Where(a => a.StartTime.Value.Year == date.Year 
    && a.StartTime.Value.Month == date.Month)
```

Comment: @stpdevi wouldn't that only return the current month?

Comment: Which is why the query is saying "return values where the year equals the current year **and** the month equals the current month

Comment: Hehe, he ninja deleted.